# React - Adding props.something as a dependency of useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, destructuring

I have this useEffect code here:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (status === "completed" && !error) 
      props.onAddedComment();
  }, [status,error,props.onAddedComment]);
```

**But I get this warning in the terminal:**
*React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'props'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. However, 'props' will change when *any* prop changes, so the preferred fix is to destructure the 'props' object outside of the useEffect call and refer to those specific props inside useEffect*

Why do I need to use destructuring if I'm passing `props.onAddedComment` and not the whole props object? would it still refer to the whole props even if I'm adding the `.onAddedComment`?

I have the same question with using `params`, in this code:

```
useEffect(() => {
    sendRequest(params.quoteId);
  }, [params.quoteId, sendRequest]);
```

I didn't get this warning here, so why?

In short, my question is if I should always use destructuring even if I'm adding `.something` after the props, and why isn't it warning me with the params.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree, I don't see how the warning makes sense either - I might be missing something, but `[status,error,props.onAddedComment]` looks just fine

Comment: Yeah, and it actually works fine too so I really don't understand why it's warning me.

Comment: Just guess when you destructure you subscribe to new object, but when you try to access via key the root object remains the same that’s why there is warning there

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16265#issuecomment-517518539
Basically it's plain JS behavior realated, when function receives "this" context and in this case this referes to props object. As props object changes on every render, "this" changes, hence new this passed to function onAddedComment. So it technically changes when props changes, even though react didn't know you probably not using this keyword in function itself. You can alternatively assign new reference to your function in useEffect const func = props.onAddedComment and there should be no issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks [to Andrius](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72757679/react-adding-props-something-as-a-dependency-of-useeffect/72757799#comment128513620_72757679) for finding this. See [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/16265#issuecomment-517518539).

When you invoke a function as part of an object, it's possible that the behavior function also depends on which object is being used, *even if the function itself doesn't change*. Here's a minimal example of why

```
useEffect(() => {
  obj.fn();
}, [obj.fn]);
```

could be a problem:

```js
const Child = ({ obj }) => {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    obj.fn();
  }, [obj.fn]);
  return null;
};
const App = () => {
  console.log('App rendering');
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  // This fn is stable across renders
  const [fn] = React.useState(() => function() { console.log('count is', this.count); });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('Calling setCount; expecting obj.fn to be called again');
      setCount(count + 1);
    }, 1000);
  }, []);
  return <Child obj={{ count, fn }} />
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

The point of exhaustive-deps is to get you to call the effect callback when anything inside the callback changes. Because it's theoretically possible for a change to an object to produce a change in the logic executed *if the object has a method*, the object itself should be added to the dependency array.

This does not produce an error:

```
useEffect(() => {
  sendRequest(params.quoteId);
}, [params.quoteId, sendRequest]);
```

because `quoteId` is not a function you're invoking; the `this` of `params` does not matter, in contrast to my above snippet and your original code, in which case a `this` of `props` could theoretically matter.

If you had done instead

```
useEffect(() => {
  sendRequest(params.getQuoteId());
}, [params.getQuoteId, sendRequest]);
```

That would have produced the warning, because now the invocation of `getQuoteId` depends on what `params` is.

Removing the function from the object and putting the function into a standalone identifier also removes the warning, because calling a function as a standalone identifier instead of as part of an object removes the possible dependency the function has on the object - the `this` inside the function no longer references the object, but `undefined`.

One way to think of it is that when you invoke a function as part of an object, the object itself is passed as a hidden additional parameter to the function, as the `this` inside the function.

This:

```
useEffect(() => {
  obj.fn();
}, [obj.fn]);
```

is like doing

```
const { obj } = fn;
useEffect(() => {
  fn.call(obj)
}, [fn]);
```

which is clearly missing `obj` as a dependency - even if the `fn`'s implementation does not consider its `this` at all.

Comment: Nice example!  I am wondering if there is any practical example where you would like to pass whole object as dependency instead of destructuring it's functions as you will lose "this" context and you can not know (in case of third party library) if this context is used in function call. Even React recommends destructuring, but then this === undefined and unexpected behavior may happen. Or it will be bad practices for developer to write an object with function property that's body relies on other object properties?